# How to limit acess to API by user?

Tags: api

I design an API and for security reasons i would like to limit call at 5calls/user/hour
The problem it's a public API so i doesn't know user. 
Have you a idea to limit access to an API ?

Comment: Only thing you can do really is rate limit the IP address

Comment: Ok i think i wiil use fail2ban to do this. thank

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameters of the Api calls can be the UserName and UserPassword. Force https encryption on both ends.